# Using an array to define type in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

The Draft 04 of JSON Schema allows for an array of string values as a valid value for the `type` property ([5.5.2.1](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor79)). How is this array to be interpreted? I can think of three options, but the spec is non-specific.

1. Primitive types,
2. A direct reference to a defined type, or
3. An inline-defined enum.

Comment: You may want to consider converting your edit into an answer.

Comment: I have to wait a bit first...

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the spec note, I saw this:

> String values MUST be one of the seven primitive types defined by the core specification.

It seems the array is used as a shorthand for a `oneOf` schema when all candidates are primitive types.